# MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC4 during JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In one of my controller actions,when I return a more than 10000 rows JsonResult to the view.
I will get the below exceptions.

Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
[image]

I have setted the maxJsonLength property in the web.config to a higher value unfortunately does not show any effect like below:

```html
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

And I also set the MaxJsonLength when I used Json class like below:

```
    public JsonResult GetList(GridPager pager, string queryStr)
    {
        List<SysExceptionModel> list = _exceptionBLL.GetList(ref pager, queryStr);
        var json = new
        {
            total = pager.totalRows,
            rows = list.ToArray()
        };

        var jsonresults = Json(json);
        jsonresults.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonresults;
    }
```

These two settings would not help me.
I was confused.

one row is like below:

0000688A-85F5-4F72-BE86-85BCADED2DE NULL BBBB BBBB BBBB BBBB BBBB 2015-10-22 02:27:38.000

Comment: For your image, use `serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;` before serializing data. Try `var jsonresults = Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` for code snippet.

Comment: Yes, It do works.Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, try setting the `MaxJsonLength` property directly on the `JavaScriptSerializer` instance.  Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx), it does not use the `jsonSerialization` element of the configuration file when you explicitly create an instance of the serializer.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NewtonSoft.Json library instead. Or try to override the JsonResult like in this example: [CustomJsonResult](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/ajax-bound-grid-custom-json-result/KendoUIMVC5/Serialization/CustomJsonResult.cs)

Setting the max jsonSerialization in the xml does not always work.

Comment: Thank you so much.Appreciate.